# Thingsboard - Custom timeseries widget injected with Chart.js library

Tags: highcharts, chart.js, thingsboard, timeserieschart

I want to create my linear timeseries widget in thingsboard but i need some custom features not included in the default version.

Configuration provided as an example byThingsboard:

The Chart.js library: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js
HTML Canvas:   
JS Code:

```
var myChart;

self.onInit = function() {
    
    var chartData = {
        datasets: []
    };

    for (var i=0; i < self.ctx.data.length; i++) {
        var dataKey = self.ctx.data[i].dataKey;
        var dataset = {
            label: dataKey.label,
            data: [],
            borderColor: dataKey.color,
            fill: false
        };
        chartData.datasets.push(dataset);
    }
    
    var options = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            ticks: {
                maxRotation: 0,
                autoSkipPadding: 30
            }
        }]
    }
    };
    
    var canvasElement = $('#myChart', self.ctx.$container)[0];
    var canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    myChart = new Chart(canvasCtx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartData,
        options: options
    });
    self.onResize();
}

self.onResize = function() {
    myChart.resize();
}

self.onDataUpdated = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.ctx.data.length; i++) {
        var datasourceData = self.ctx.data[i];
        var dataSet = datasourceData.data;
        myChart.data.datasets[i].data.length = 0;
        var data = myChart.data.datasets[i].data;
        for (var d = 0; d < dataSet.length; d++) {
            var tsValuePair = dataSet[d];
            var ts = tsValuePair[0];
            var value = tsValuePair[1];
            data.push({t: ts, y: value});
        }
    }
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min = self.ctx.timeWindow.minTime;
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max = self.ctx.timeWindow.maxTime;
    myChart.update();
}
```

And the output:

[Thingsboard timeseries example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHElg.png)

Well as you can see the X axis its defined as time and the "First" and "Second" are the datasource generated by the ctx object.

-So what do i need?
As you can see both datasource coloured never change and i want to change the color by the following situations:
if the value of (Y axis is > 50 and < 70 ) and during 6min (X axis) then colour green
if the value of (Y axis is > 70 and < 90 ) and during 6min (X axis) then colour orange
if the value of (Y axis is > 90 ) and during 6min (X axis) then colour red
By default the colour will be grey lets say in this example.

I have tried to create the chart using the Chart.js library and inject it in TB but the X axis isn not the same as i expected because i need the same X axis like i showed before in the picture above.

Also i have tried this with another library, Highcharts, but the result is this:
[HighCharts try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO1t2.png)

The library used: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.3/highcharts.min.js

```
self.onInit = function() {
    //self.ctx.flot = new TbFlot(self.ctx);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            color: {
                linearGradient: [500, 0, 100, 0],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'red'],
                    [1, 'green']
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
}
```

My knowledge about JS is basic and im investigating how this charts works for this libraries but i dont get how TB charts works, exclusively how the X axis works and update.

X axis Update method:

````
self.onDataUpdated = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.ctx.data.length; i++) {
        var datasourceData = self.ctx.data[i];
        var dataSet = datasourceData.data;
        myChart.data.datasets[i].data.length = 0;
        var data = myChart.data.datasets[i].data;
        for (var d = 0; d < dataSet.length; d++) {
            var tsValuePair = dataSet[d];
            var ts = tsValuePair[0];
            var value = tsValuePair[1];
            data.push({t: ts, y: value});
        }
    }
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min = self.ctx.timeWindow.minTime;
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max = self.ctx.timeWindow.maxTime;
    myChart.update();
}```

Note: depending which version of the library we use this method changes.

If anyone who experimented or created before a custom timeseries chart in TB please let me know any useful information because from TB i didnt find to many helpful documentation.

PD: its my first time creating a question in StackOverflow
````

Answer (score 0):

The required behaviour is achievable in Highcharts by using `zones`, but requires some customization if you want to apply the duration check.

Below is an example of adding zones dynamically, based on point value and trend time length.

```
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const zones = [];
        const sixMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 6;

        function updateTime(timeObj, color, timestamp) {
          // check time for other colors
          for (let key in timeObj) {
            if (key !== color && key !== 'passed' && timeObj[key]) {
              if (timeObj.passed > sixMinutes) {
                zones.push({
                  color: 'grey',
                  value: timeObj[key]
                }, {
                  value: timeObj[key] + timeObj.passed,
                  color: key
                });
              }
              timeObj[key] = 0;
              timeObj.passed = 0;
            }
          }
          // save current trend
          if (timeObj[color]) {
            timeObj.passed = timestamp - timeObj[color];
          } else {
            timeObj[color] = timestamp;
          }
        }

        this.series.forEach(s => {
          const time = {
            green: 0,
            orange: 0,
            red: 0,
            passed: 0
          };

          s.points.forEach(p => {
            if (p.y > 50 && p.y < 70) {
              updateTime(time, 'green', p.x);
            } else if (p.y > 70 && p.y < 90) {
              updateTime(time, 'orange', p.x);
            } else if (p.y > 90) {
              updateTime(time, 'red', p.x);
            } else {
              updateTime(time, null, p.x);
            }
          });

          s.update({
            zones
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jt0p9a3d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#zones

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ppotaczek. I will try to implement this solution in ThingsBoard. My biggest challenge its to adapt it to Thingsboard due to the Update X axis function.

Comment: Hi @Denis Pintea, I don't know Thingsboard, but with pure Highcharts you don't need to update x-axis.